# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android' Y it is showing this error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My activity_main xml is not loading correctly it is giving that error.
it is showing the path error in \res\menu\main.xml:3

and my main.xml is :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

and here is my manifest file. Help will be much appreciated. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javacodegeeks.android.audiocapturetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.audiocapturetest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you using ActionBarActivity from the support library or ActionbarSherlock?

Comment: The android:showAsAction attribute is available only on Android 3.0 (API Level 11) and greater.Your min sdk seems to be 10.Also make sure your're using a  API 11+ sdk to compile this.
Check the footnote of this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html